# Understanding inductance and its dependency with frequency

Tags: inductor, pulse, high-frequency, frequency-measurement, esr

I am trying to understand how to design an inductor that has  constant parameters over  a wide range of frequencies. Especially over high frequencies because I want to use them for impulse testing  which have a characteristic frequency around up to 100kHz.

- What exactly makes the inductance of a real inductor change at diferent frequencies?
- What is the effect of the core in this dependency? (With or without iron core, for example.)
- What has to be considered in the design to minimize the skin effect so as to have a low ESR?

Additional info:

To illustrate this, I have five different inductors for which I have performed Ls and Rs measurements on an Agilent E4980A RLC meter:

[image]

All of these inductors have a decently constant Ls value from 50 Hz to 300kHz, but their ESR behavior differs.

[image]

Comment: Why is inductor #2's inductance at 300 kHz in volts? Are you sure you were always measuring series resistance?

Comment: @Andyaka My bad, that is supposed to be μH instead V. But yeah pretty sure I was measuring Ls and Rs since those are the output values of the LCR meter

Comment: [Wide band inductors might look a little like this.](https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/products/rf/conical-broadband/0-40-ghz/bcl/)

Comment: @periblepsis Do you have any idea on why this design is helpfull for wide-band applications? Thank you though!

Comment: @SantiOspina You may want to start by reading ["Radiation Field of a Conical Helix"](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jap/article-abstract/24/5/550/160446/Radiation-Field-of-a-Conical-Helix), by J. S. Chatterjee. And then read his paper called *"A Wide-Band Oscillator Using a Conical-Helix Tuning Inductor"*, published the following year.

Comment: @SantiOspina Hmm. I found this [*"A Broadband Microwave Choke"*](https://www.microwavejournal.com/articles/2809-a-broadband-microwave-choke). May also help. And, of course, CoilCraft's own page [discussing why](https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/edu/series/what-is-a-conical-inductor/) might be worth a skim, as well. Both pages are consistent with each others' argument.

Comment: @SantiOspina These may perhaps be the best few papers: [*"Conical Inductors for Broadband Applications"*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1418000) and [*"Lumped Circuit Model of Conical Shape Inductors for Broad-Bandwidth Applications"*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7439819) and [*"Field Gradient Analysis of a Conical Helix"*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/195552). I'm finding buckets of papers, though. You should do a search, I think.

Comment: @periblepsis Thank you very much!